# How to lock all keyboard and device input on Linux when a device doesn't exist

Tags: linux

I run Arch Linux with a LUKS encrypted partition. `/efi` and `/boot` are not encrypted, but I am not too worried about the data on those.

I am using a 'detached' header that is kept on a usb flash drive (don't worry I have a backup in a fireproof safe, and an encrypted backup somewhere else). The nice part about this is that it requires both the USB drive to be inserted, and to enter my password to decrypt the drive.

This is all just a backstory to what I want to accomplish. If I am sitting at my desk, and want to go to the bathroom or coffee, I want to just pull the usb drive out. When this drive is removed, I want gdm to lock, and all input to the machine to be blocked - no mouse, no keyboard, no bluetooth. Possibly some other scenarios I haven't though of. I want to leave the system running (compiling code, etc.), but prevent anybody from being able to log in. When the usb drive (which just happens to contain the header) is inserted, it will unblock the mouse/keyboard and allow me to login.

Looking for novel ways of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this fairly easily once I started researching it but it took a bit of trial and error to get it right. I'll document here in case anybody else wants to do something similar.

First was for me to create some udev rules to run scripts on actions. You will need to find the correct attributes from udevadm by doing `udevadm info -a -n /dev/sdb` and at the same time look for the modules under DRIVERS section.

`/etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb-addremove-triggers.rules`

```
ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{PRODUCT}=="930/6530/10", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", RUN+="/usr/bin/sh /root/source/usb/remove.sh"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{PRODUCT}=="930/6530/10", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", RUN+="/usr/bin/sh /root/source/usb/add.sh"
```

I then added 2 files in `/root/source/usb`: `remove.sh` and `add.sh`. Technically these could be combined and you could pass the action in, but I chose to keep them separate.

For these files, I want to:

1. Lock the screen
2. Disable the keyboard
3. Disable the mouse
4. Block bluetooth

`/root/source/usb/remove.sh`

```
rfkill block bluetooth
loginctl lock-sessions
modprobe -r usbhid
modprobe -r i2c_hid_acpi
```

`/root/source/usb/add.sh`

```
rfkill unblock bluetooth
modprobe usbhid
modprobe i2c_hid_acpi
```